# What Metrics To Use on Google Analytics Add on in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the google analytics add on for google sheets which lets me automatically pull usage data out of analytics to use in my google sheets.
I usually use them in the following format:

```
Column A: Date (DAY)
Column B: Eventtype
Column C: Event Value
```

I have managed to do this with events, but am not able to do it with regular usage data like Unique Visitors or Session length.
I would like to get:

```
Column A: Date (DAY)
Column B: Unique Visitors
Column C: Average Session Length
```

QUESTION:
What parameters do I need as Metrics, Dimensions, Order & Filters?

Comment: You should contact the developer of your plugin.

Comment: It's a standard Google-Plugin using the regular Google-Analytics-API. The question can be answered by someone who understands the API.

Comment: I am an expert in this API and wrote several of the sample codes for this API currently on the Developer website.  And i cant help you with google sheets or a plugin.   Have you tried checking the [
Dimensions & Metrics Explorer]https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Comment: Okay, I managed to "brute force" it. Answer follows.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters needed for this case are.

**Metrics:** ga:users ga:sessionDuration
**Dimensions:** ga:date ga:year ga:month